# Textbox when Other option selected from combobox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wonder if it is possible (OOTB) in a combobox column, when other option selected, a textbox is displayed and user enters custom text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column to the list named "Other" as single line of text type. Then you can make use of jQuery to show the textbox only when the user selects other in the combo box. This column will only have values when combo box value is other.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the column to allow fill in options.

A way I've done this is the past is to create a list to store my column values. Then in my desired list, create a lookup column to that list and set it to allow fill ins. Then with a workflow on item creation or change, if a user enters a fill in option, I create that entry in my list and then update the item to that newly created value.